# How to hidde a directory or a folder with the Set-itemProperty command?

Tags: powershell, system.io.file, system.io.directory

```
$Path|Set-ItemProperty -name Hidden -Value $true
$Path|Set-ItemProperty -name isHidden -Value $true
Set-ItemProperty -path $Path -name isHidden -Value $true

#Error: Set-ItemProperty: The property bool isHidden=False does not exist or was not found.
```

There is no argument completion for `-name` property, so its hard to tell what it supports or not. I know how to lock a file with it, only because it is one of the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.4#example-1-set-a-property-of-a-file) in the docs:

```
$Path|Set-ItemProperty -name IsReadOnly -Value $true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77909604/45375) provides an effective solution that relies on direct use of .NET type members.

An even simpler solution is to use the standard [`attrib.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) utility, whose sole purpose is to manage file attributes:

```bash
# Turn on the Hidden attribute; -h would turn it off.
attrib +h $Path
```

---

As for using [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty):

On Windows,<sup>[1]</sup> it is the `Attributes` property that you need to target, and while
`Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name Attributes -Value Hidden` *does* work in principle, the *caveat* is:

- The `-Value` argument invariably *fully replaces* the existing attributes, so that you'd need to make sure to also include any *preexisting* attributes in order to preserve them if your intent is to *selectively set* attributes:<sup>[2]</sup>

  - E.g., if the target item has the `Archive` attribute set, and you needed to preserve that, you'd need to specify `-Value 'Hidden, Archive'`.

    - That is, you'd need to specify a single string containing a `,`-separated list of the symbolic names of [`System.IO.FileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileAttributes) enumeration values, relying on PowerShell's convenient to-and-from-*string* conversion of [`System.Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum)-derived types.
      (The cumbersome type-exact equivalent of the above would be:
      `-Value ([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive)`)
    - Thus, in order to *clear* all attributes (that can be cleared), pass `-Value 'None'`
  - Operating on the `.Attributes` property of [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemInfo) instances, as output by [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) or [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), makes basing the updated value on the existing attributes easier, as shown in Santiago's answer.

---

<sup>[1] On *Unix*-like platforms, visibility is determined simply by an item's (file or directory's) *name*: if the name starts with `.`, the item is considered to be hidden. macOS, specifically, supports an additional mechanism for hiding items, via *extended file-system attributes*.</sup>

<sup>[2] The `Directory` attribute is special, however: it is *invariably* set for *directories* and cannot be cleared.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use `Set-ItemProperty`, hiding a file or folder can be done by adding the [`FileAttributes.Hidden`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-8.0) flag to the [`.Attributes` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes?view=net-8.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-attributes) of a `FileSystemInfo` instance (base class of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`):

```bash
$fileOrFolder = Get-Item path\to\fileORfolder
$fileOrFolder.Attributes = $fileOrFolder.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden
```

Same applies for [`.IsReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly?view=net-8.0) you can set it to `$true` or `$false` at ease:

```
$fileOrFolder.IsReadOnly = $true
```

If you want to get a better understanding on what you can *set* on a file or folder I recommend you to go to the .NET docs, look for the [**Properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-8.0#properties) section and then look for **settable** properties (where it says *"Gets or **sets***...").